# How to get the key by index in Hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I try to get the value of the key in a `Hashtable` based on the index position I provide, this is my hashtable:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> hash_table = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
hash_table.put(5, "This");
hash_table.put(7, "Is");
hash_table.put(10, "Hashtable");
```

To get the value of the key based on the index position, I wrote a method as follows:

```
public static Integer getKeyByIndex(Hashtable<Integer, String> hashtable, int index) {
    Integer keyValue = null;
    if(index < 0 || index > hashtable.size() - 1) {
        return keyValue;
    }
    Enumeration<Integer> enu = hashtable.keys();
    for(int i = 0; enu.hasMoreElements();) {
        keyValue = enu.nextElement();
        if(i == index) {
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return keyValue;
}
```

The above method, although operating correctly, it seems long and has not been optimized. So I want to know if there is a brief way?

I will appreciate the solutions you give.

Comment: Mapping structures like Hashtable (why are you not using `Map` instead) don't have the notion of "indexing".  You use the key to extract the value.  Here, all of your keys are integers.  Are you asking how to pull the value out given the specified key?

Comment: @Makoto I want to extract the key based on the current index. The key here acts as tabs, when moving to a certain tab, I need to extract the key (K) to get the value (V) because my key isn't the index form 0, 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: What is "current index"?  The index you're passing into the function?

Comment: @Makoto I will use the example: Browser is the Hashtable. In there:
The current index is the position of the tab you are view.
Key (K) is the PID of the tab. Each tab will have a different PID.
Value (V) is the content of the tab.
So I need to get the PID of the tab you are view.
Therefore, I created a method of putting the entire existing tab and the index of the tab is viewing, the result returned as the PID of that tab.

Comment: @TầnQuảng are you trying to find the key by value?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what it is you're asking.  How does `hashtable.get(index)` not work for you in this context?

Comment: @Makoto Based on the [Hashtable document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), `Hashtable` itself has no `get(index)` method as you said, it only has `get(key)`.

Comment: @TầnQuảng:  The key you refer to in documentation would be your `index` variable, which is what I'm alluding to.  If you call `hashtable.get(index)` with your actual index variable (and you *might* have to box that into an `Integer` but I don't think you need to), is that *not* sufficient?

Comment: @Makoto In the code I give, if you use `hashtable.get(0)` or `hashtable.get(1)` even `hashtable.get((Integer)0)` or `hashtable.get((Integer)1)`, you will receive `null`. As I said on above, `Hashtable` / `Map` currently there is no `get(index)` method like `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WJS noted, the correct way to go is with a `LinkedHashMap` which maintains insertion order (as the iteration order on key/value pairs).
As an improvement to solutions proposed, we can extract the i-th key without populating a full array/list of the map keys (which can be rather inefficient) using O(1) memory.

Let `map` be a `LinkedHashMap` :

```java
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(99,"fu");
map.put(33, "bar");
map.put(5, "foo");
```

##### Solution with streams

```java
static <K,V> K getKeyByIndex(LinkedHashMap<K,V> map, int index)
{
    return map.keySet().stream().skip(index).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

##### Solution with plain iterators

```java
static <K,V> K getKeyByIndex(LinkedHashMap<K,V> map, int index)
{
    final Iterator<K> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index && it.hasNext(); ++i) {
        it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext()? it.next() : null;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious `using O(1) memory` that you say is for both solutions or for the solution `Solution with streams` or `Solution with plain iterators`?

Comment: Do you mean about the solution with streams? It depends, of course, on the JDK implementation of `skip` and `findFirst` method calls. But, i suppose that `skip` does not store previously rejected items, and `findFirst` just extracts the first item and terminates the stream.

Comment: I mean `using O(1) memory` that you say is for the `Solution with streams` or `Solution with plain iterators`? Or for both solution? Simple understanding is: Do both of the solutions you give is `using O(1) memory`?

Comment: The iterator solution is certainly of O(1) memory. The streams solution is presumably of O(1) memory (unless something some surprise is hidden in the implementation of `Stream.skip` and `Stream.findFirst` methods)

Answer (score 1):

Maps don't have the concept of being indexed as the keys are unordered.  But you can preserve the insertion order by using a LinkedHashMap.  So if you want to get say the `nth` value you inserted, then the following will work for you.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(5, "This");
map.put(7, "Is");
map.put(10, "Hashtable");
map.put(100,"foo");
map.put(99,"bar");

int v = getKeyByIndex(map, 2);
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
10
```

- `LinkedHashMap` uses a `LinkedKeySet` to maintain insertion order.
- map the keys to an array.
- and index the array using the supplied index.
- By using generic type parameters you can use the method for any `LinkedHashMap` regardless of the key/value types.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K,V> K getKeyByIndex(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map, int index) {
    K keyValue = null;
    if(index < 0 || index >= map.size()) {
        return keyValue;
    }

    Iterator<K> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        it.next();
    }
    return it.next();
}
```

Comment: Your `getKeyByIndex` method also uses O(1) memory, right?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean.  The method does not alter any allocated memory at all.   The lookup time varies depending on the index since it must iterate over the array.  Internally, returning the array required iterating over the entire array so I adapted that to short circuit the lookup.